# Looping over multiple commands

Tags: powershell, foreach, hashtable

I'm writing a script that should output pending changes for multiple workspaces in TFS (Team Foundation Server).

So far I've got this:

```
$collection="http://tfs-abc/"

$stats = @{
    #'WS1' = tf stat /workspace:"WS1" /collection:$collection | select -last 1,
    'WS2' = tf stat /workspace:"WS2" /collection:$collection | select -last 1
}

$stats.Keys | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "$_ - $($stats[$_])" }
```

It only works with a single item and produces:

> WS2 - 45 change(s), 263 detected change(s)

If I uncomment the first workspace then it doesn't work anymore and says:

> Select-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Int32' required by parameter 'Last'.

Comment: use a ";" instead of a "," in your hash.

Comment: unbelievable, this really works, thank you @DavidBrabant ;-)

Comment: or just get rid of the ",", a linebreak works fine by its own. ;)

Comment: @whatever, you want to write that up as a full answer?

Comment: Sure, hope David Brabant doesn't mind me stealing his fame for the (first) answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the "," between the two lines, elements in hashes need to be seperated by ";" or by linebreaks:

```
$collection="http://tfs-abc/"

$stats = @{
'WS1' = tf stat /workspace:"WS1" /collection:$collection | select -last 1
'WS2' = tf stat /workspace:"WS2" /collection:$collection | select -last 1
}

$stats.Keys | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "$_ - $($stats[$_])" }
```

"," is used in powershell to seperate listitems like

```
$Var = @("a","b","c")
```